# Call to a member function bind_param() on a non-object - PHP

Tags: php, forms, mysqli

I've tried everything, looked at questions on stackoverflow, google it, check the documentation. But nothing works. It just keeps saying

```
Call to a member function bind_param() on a non-object
```

This is the original code that was not functioning as intended

Here's the code:

```
<?php
    ob_start();

    $myusername = @$_POST['username'];
    $mypassword = @$_POST['password'];

    if (isset($_POST['logged'])) {
    $myusername = stripslashes($myusername);
    $mypassword = stripslashes($mypassword);
    $myusername = mysql_real_escape_string($myusername);
    $mypassword = mysql_real_escape_string($mypassword);
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM members WHERE username='$myusername'";
    $sql->bind_param("s", $sql);
    $result = mysql_query($sql);

    $count = mysql_num_rows($result);

    if (!empty($myusername) && !empty($mypassword)) {
        if($count == 1) {
            $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
            if (md5($mypassword) == $row['password']) {
                $_SESSION['username'] = $myusername;
                $_SESSION['first_name'] = $row['first_name'];
                $_SESSION['last_name'] = $row['last_name'];
                $_SESSION['email'] = $row['email'];
                $_SESSION['loggedIn'] = true;
            }
            else {
                echo "<p style=\"color: red\">Wrong Password</p>";
            }
        }
        else {
            echo "<p style=\"color: red\">Wrong Username</p>";
        }
    }
    else {
        echo "<p style=\"color: red\">Fill in all fields</p>";
    }
}
?>
```

Here's the updated code.

**UPDATE**

```
<?php
    ob_start();

    $myusername = @$_POST['username'];
    $mypassword = @$_POST['password'];

    if (isset($_POST['logged'])) {
        //$myusername = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $myusername);
        //$mypassword = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $mypassword);
        $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM members WHERE username=? AND password=md5(?)") or die($conn->error); //UPDATE
        $stmt->bind_param("ss", $myusername, $mypassword);
        $stmt->execute() or die($conn->error);
        $stmt->store_result();
        $count = $stmt->num_rows();

        if (!empty($myusername) && !empty($mypassword)) {
            if($count == 1) {
                $result = $stmt->get_result();
                $row = $result->fetch_array();
                $_SESSION['username'] = $myusername;
                $_SESSION['first_name'] = $row['first_name'];
                $_SESSION['last_name'] = $row['last_name'];
                $_SESSION['email'] = $row['email'];
                $_SESSION['loggedIn'] = true;
            }
            else {
                echo "<p style=\"color: red\">Wrong Username or Password</p>";
            }
        }
        else {
            echo "<p style=\"color: red\">Fill in all fields</p>";
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: Why are you calling `bind_param` when there are no parameters in your query? It seems like you're just totally misunderstanding how to call `mysqli` functions.

Comment: you're also mixing mysql and mysqli functions, you can't do that.

Comment: Why do you strip slashes from the password?

Comment: No, I set up the mysqli on another page that links to this one.

Comment: But you're calling mysql_real_escape_string instead of mysqli_real_escape_string.

Comment: You definitely and **desperately** need to read tutorials again.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about not using the proper syntax or APIs required for a successful query.

Comment: Oh, yes Okay got that. But what about the part that says bind_param() can that be fixed?

Answer (score 2):

`$stmt` isn't an object, it's a string. Hence, "Call to a member function bind_param() on a non-object".

You need to create an actual statement from that query.

Comment: That's not the only issue. OP is mixing MySQL APIs, not to mention probable missing `session_start();`. Too many things wrong with OP's code.

Comment: True. But his question is specifically about that error. I think this is one of those times where jumping into everything that is wrong would take all day.

Comment: Exactly. All the more reasons I tend to shy away from questions as such.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Listen buddy, if I got those errors I would fix them. But I didn't get them so that means I already added that code.

Comment: Sigh. Good luck getting help if you get defensive when people point out glaring holes in your code.

Comment: @jraede I fixed the mysql mixing that he mentioned and i already had the `session_start()` Why can't you understand?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM members WHERE username = ? AND password = md5(?)" 
        or die ($db->error);
    $stmt->bind_param("ss", $username, $password);
    $stmt->execute() or die($stmt->error);
    $stmt->store_result();
    $count = $stmt->num_rows();
```

You don't need to use `stripslashes` or escape the string when you use parameters in the query. You have to call `prepare()` to turn the SQL into a statement. You pass the parameter values to `bind_param`, not the SQL statement. `execute` returns a boolean that indicates whether the query succeeded, you call `num_rows` on the statement itself.

When using a prepared query, you replace the values that you want to substitute with `?` placeholders. These then get filled in with the variables named in `bind_param`. You should NOT call `mysqli_real_escape_string` when you're using parameters in a prepared statement.

If you just follow the examples in the PHP mysqli documentation you should have been able to see all these steps correctly.

Comment: Did that. Now it says unknown column 'epicman2456' (the username in the database) in 'where clause' And I swear that username is in the database.

Comment: I think you didn't change `$username` in the query to `?`.

Comment: I did change it. Still says the same thing.

Comment: There's no way you should be getting that error if your statement is as I wrote. Please update your question with the current code. Put it at the end as an UPDATE, don't change the original code in the question -- that needs to be saved for posterity so that readers can see what the original problem was.

Comment: You still have `WHERE username=$username` instead of `WHERE username=?`. You lied when you said you fixed that.

Comment: Get rid of the calls to `mysqli_real_escape_string`. You should not use that when you're using prepared statements.

Comment: Sigh. Now it just says Wrong username or Password even though I typed in the EXACT username and password as it was in the database, I even added another account that had a username and pass of 'e' yet it still says that.

Comment: When you create the account, you put `MD5(password)` in the password field?

Comment: Yep. I quadruple checked that it was encrypted in md5.

Comment: Forgot to call `store_result` before calling `num_rows`. Try adding that as in my update.

Comment: Okay, That threw an error, `Fatal error: Call to undefined method mysqli_stmt::fetch_array()` But then I realised I needed to add `$stmt = $stmt->get_result()` then that threw an error `Fatal error: Call to a member function fetch_array() on a non-object` then I moved the `store_result()` thing over up a line so it's after the `bind_param()` and then that said `Wrong username or password`

Comment: I'm getting lost in all the changes you're making, please add the latest version to the question.

Comment: Okay I added the one that that throws the error `Fatal error: Call to a member function fetch_array() on a non-object`